# Problem with the border width of the image view inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView. It has only one section and multiple cells in that section (currently 6). Inside the cell, there is an imageview(with round corner radius) and a label. Whenever a cell is selected, I want to add a border around that cell's imageview. Whenever a cell is selected, the "didSelectItemAt" is called. The "didDeselectItemAt" is also called. If the cell is visible, I am able to remove its border by setting the borderWidth to 0.0.

Currently, only 4 cells are visible at a time in the collectionview.

I do the following steps:
1. Select the 2nd cell.
2. Select the 5th cell.
Expectation: The border of the 2nd cell's image view should become 0
Actual Behaviour: Both the cells have the borderWitdth as non 0 value.
Same happens for the vice versa selection

Apart from this, I do the following also.
1. Select the 1st cell.
2. Select the 6th cell.
Expectation: The border of the 21st cell's image view should become 0
Actual Behaviour: The border of both the cells is visible. Only after dragging too much, the borderWidth of the 1st cell becomes 0.
Same happens for the vice versa selection.

Following is my View Controller code.

```
private var selectedCategory : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        vibeCategoriesCollectionView.delegate = self
        vibeCategoriesCollectionView.dataSource = self
        vibeCategoriesCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "vibeCategoryCell")
        vibeCategoriesCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        vibeCategoriesCollectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return VibeCategories.pickerStrings.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 6, height: vibeCategoriesCollectionView.frame.height)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = vibeCategoriesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "vibeCategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.categoryName.text = VibeCategories.pickerStrings[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: VibeCategories.categoryImages[indexPath.row])
        cell.categoryName.textColor = VibeCategories.vibeColors[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryImage.layer.borderColor = VibeCategories.vibeColors[indexPath.row].cgColor
        if selectedCategory != indexPath.row {
            cell.categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let currentSelectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell
        currentSelectedCell.categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        selectedCategory = indexPath.row
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let previousSelectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell
        if previousSelectedCell != nil {
            previousSelectedCell!.categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        }
    }
```

Following is my CollectionViewCell class code

```
class VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutIfNeeded() {
        super.layoutIfNeeded()

        categoryImage.layer.cornerRadius = categoryImage.frame.height / 2
        categoryImage.clipsToBounds = true
        categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        notificationLabel.layer.cornerRadius = notificationLabel.frame.height / 2
        notificationLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: change your border in your `VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell` class.  `override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            
            if isSelected {
               
                
            } else {
                
                
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Thi worked. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your `cellForItemAt` function right before the `return` statement:

```
cell.categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = (collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? []).contains(indexPath) ? 4 : 0
```

Also move the line `categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = 4.0` from the cell's `layoutIfNeeded` to the `awakeFromNib` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//      changing the current selected to not selected
        let currentSelectedIndex = IndexPath(item: selectedCategory, section: 0)
        let currentSelectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: currentSelectedIndex) as! VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell
        currentSelectedCell.categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [currentSelectedIndex])


//      changing the new selected to selected
        selectedCategory = indexPath.row
        let newSelectedCell = vibeCategoriesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "vibeCategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! VibeCategoryCollectionViewCell
        newSelectedCell.categoryImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

    }
```